# Web2py Failed login count and reusing old passwords

Tags: authentication, web2py

I'm trying to implement a couple authentication features, but am not too sure where to start.

I'd like to disable an account after it has reached a certain number of failed attempts, and prevent users from reusing previous passwords. Currently, I'm using the auth sql tables provided with web2py and plan on adding a couple columns to the auth_user table.

Within web2py, where would I validate against these new table columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Auth settings callbacks.

I think you're looking for this callback `auth.settings.on_failed_authentication`. Write a function that handles the logic from here.

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages